# unable to click element in iframe of webpage

Tags: selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

i have a button named "Authenticated" in iframe ,
using below code in behat featurecontext file for clicking it.

```
$this->getSession()->getDriver()->executeScript("jQuery( document    ).ready(function() {
                                                        var frame = $(iframe[name='datacash-payment-frame']).get(0).contentDocument;
                                                        $(input[name='choice'][value='Authenticated'],frame).click(function() {
                                                            alert(\'fgsdfgsdgs\');
                                                        });
                                                        });     
                                                    ");
```

Getting error that " illegal character"

Comment: Why are you using jQuery? What's wrong with the standard `findElement` methods?

Comment: actually I am using behat framework for testing drupal based websites.currently working on a test where I click on button which submits a page while doing credit card payment and shortly after that click on back browser button.In a normal flow in browser, I am able to see iframe with same content,but getting problem while doing with selenium ( see code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3611‎). please suggest any solution to this.can I get click browser back button before page unloads

Comment: Did you found solution to this